# Check if string contains trailing whitespace?

Tags: javascript, regex

My text isn't guaranteed to have a trailing newline. I can do it with two regexes like this:

```js
myString.match(/[^\S\r\n]\n/) || myString.match(/[^\S\r\n]$/)
```

but can I do it with one regex?

Comment: Just `myString.match(/\s$/m)` is good enough (not my downvote)

Comment: @anubhava's solution works in this specific case, but in the general case where you have two (or more) different things to match, you can use an alternation (`|`): `/[^\S\r\n](?:\n|$)/` The `(?:___)` is a non-capturing group, and the contents are either `\n` or `$`.

Comment: @anubhava thanks! It returns true for `'first line\r\nsecond line'`, but whatever.

Comment: If you are only trying to see trailing horizontal space then use: `myString.match(/[ \t]$/m)`

Comment: If you don't mind to have heading spaces being removed as well, you can just use `.trim()`

Comment: @anubhava I care about all whitespace

Comment: @KarelG: JS has a `trimEnd()` function as well

Comment: @KarelG that has nothing to do with my question, unless you're saying I should do `line === line.trimEnd()`. I don't want to remove anything, I just want to check if a string (with multiple lines) has trailing whitespace somewhere inside it.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy: Will a value of `abc\n\n123` be considered having a trailing whitespace?

Comment: @anubhava no, that's an empty line, not a line with trailing whitespace. When I wrote my solution I was specifically thinking about that case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a non-regex and a regex approach to check trailing horizontal whitespace in a string:

```js
var arr=['foo', 'bar '];

// non-regex approach using trimEnd() function
arr.forEach(el => {
  if (el.length > el.trimEnd().length)
    console.log(el + "has trailing whitespace");
});

// regex approach that matches space or tab before line end
const rx = /[ \t]$/m;
arr.forEach(el => {
  if (rx.test(el))
    console.log(el + "has trailing whitespace");
});
```